# Cant get object from database

Tags: java, sql, database

So I have a mySQL database where i have more tables, including:

```
 Product with idProduct,name,price and quantity (INT,Varchar,double,int) types.
 Client with idClient,name,address,email (INT,varchar,varchar,varchar) types.
```

And i have the following code for a Select * from Client/Product Where idClient/idProduct=X.
The code for Client works, but the one for Product does not.

---

```
    public Product findById(int id) {
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement stmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    int idp=0;
    String nume="";
    double pret=0;
    int q=0;

    String query="Select * from Product Where idProduct="+id+";";
    int ok=0;
    try {
        con=ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs=stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            ok=1;
            idp=rs.getInt("idProduct");
            nume=rs.getString("name");
            pret=rs.getDouble("price");
            q=rs.getInt("quantity");
        }
    
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        ConnectionFactory.close(con);
        ConnectionFactory.close(stmt);
        ConnectionFactory.close(rs);
    }
    if (ok==1)
    {
    Product nou=new Product(idp,nume,pret,q);
    return nou;
    }
    else return null;
}
```

}

---

```
    public Client findById(int id) {
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement stmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    int idc=0;
    String nume="";
    String adr="";
    String em="";
    String ph="";
    String query="Select * from Client Where idClient="+id+";";
    int ok=0;
    try {
        con=ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        stmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs=stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            ok=1;
            idc=rs.getInt("idClient");
            nume=rs.getString("name");
            adr=rs.getString("address");
            em=rs.getString("email");
            ph=rs.getString("phone");
        }
    
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        ConnectionFactory.close(con);
        ConnectionFactory.close(stmt);
        ConnectionFactory.close(rs);
    }
    if (ok==1)
    {
    Client nou=new Client(idc,nume,adr,em,ph);
    return nou;
    }
    else return null;
  }'''
```

---

To me it looks exactly the same. The results are:
'''

---

```
    model.Product@32eff876
    [idClient: 1 George address: Cluj email: george@y.com phone: 0722]
```

'''

---

So It works 10/10 for Client but not for product.. Can u help me? I checked the database, everything seems ok.

This are dates i copied right from the mysql server, so the names are good, the types too. I dont know what it could be, i deleted the table and created again several times, I also recreated the entire database, but its the same

```
 Table: product
 Columns:
 idProduct int AI PK 
 name varchar(45) 
 price double 
 quantity int

 Table: client
 Columns:
 idClient int AI PK 
 name varchar(45) 
 address varchar(45) 
 email varchar(45) 
 phone varchar(45)
```

The insert statement works just fine for both of them.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? Product is showing to be non-null `model.Product@32eff876`. Add a toString method to product class.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting database tags. Please re-tag your question with just the actual database product that you are using.

Comment: @Jason, well ye, it is not null. But my Client does not have a toString method either, and it shows just fine. I will try to add it and i come back to see if this was the problem

Comment: You're not printing Client you're likely printing the ResultSet object considering the output is wrapped in [].

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula for SQL debugging:

1. Test your query in an SQL client to make sure and debug there first
2. Use the EXACT SAME QUERY as you were testing with in 1 in your code to make sure that the code works
3. Replace the hardcoded values in your Java SQL call with your variables, and print out all of your Java query parameters to make sure that they are correct. If they are, it should work!

Answer (score 0):

As indicated an earlier comment I provided solved the problem. The following just serves as way to improve your code.

`Why do you think it doesn't work? Product is showing to be non-null model.Product@32eff876. Add a toString method to product class.`

1. When you modify a query directly it's possible to perform SQL injection. Instead, provide the query and mutate the `PreparedStatement`.
2. Wrap your AutoCloseable objects in try-with-resources as to ensure the object is closed once it falls out of scope. You were doing this with ConnectionFactory#close but I would bet that method calls #close.
3. Don't set `ok` to 1 if a result is found, instead fail fast and return the result from the while loop if one exists.
4. If no result is found, don't return null, throw an exception like `IllegalStateException`

```java
    public Product findById(int id) {
        String query="SELECT * FROM Product WHERE idProduct=?;";

        try (Connection con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
            
            stmt.setInt(1, id);
            
            try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    int productId = rs.getInt("idProduct");

                    String name = rs.getString("name");

                    double price = rs.getDouble("price");

                    int quantity = rs.getInt("quantity");
                    
                    return new Product(productId, name, price, quantity);
                }
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("No product can be found for this id: %s", id));
    }
```